# substring is not working properly in Javascript, how to add starts between a string?

Tags: javascript

Actually i have a code like `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` and I want to this should be like `abcdef**************uvwxyz` but right now getting `abcdef*uvwxyz` how can i fix it?

My code:-

```js
  let str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        let firstDigit = str.substring(0, 6)
        let lastDigit = str.substring(str.length - 6)
        let mask = new String('*',str.length - firstDigit.length - lastDigit.length);
        let maskAddress = firstDigit + mask + lastDigit
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = maskAddress;
```

```html
 <div id="demo"></div>
```

TahnkYou!

Comment: `str.replace(/[^abcdefuvwxyz]/g, "*")` or `str.replace(/(.)/g, (...args) => args[2] >= 6 && args[2] <= 19? "*" : args[1] )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method to repeat a string a given amount of times.

```js
let str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        let firstDigit = str.substring(0, 6)
        let lastDigit = str.substring(str.length - 6)
        let mask = "*".repeat(str.length - firstDigit.length - lastDigit.length);
        let maskAddress = firstDigit + mask + lastDigit
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = maskAddress;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

One option seems not very good for you

```js
  let str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        let firstDigit = str.substring(0, 6)
        let lastDigit = str.substring(str.length - 6)
        let mask = "";
        for(var i=0;i<str.length - firstDigit.length - lastDigit.length;i++){
          mask +="*";
        }
        let maskAddress = firstDigit + mask + lastDigit
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = maskAddress;
```

```html
 <div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Cleaner way to do this:**

```js
  let str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  let firstDigit = str.substring(0, 6);
  let lastDigit = str.substring(str.length - 6);
  let mask = '*'.repeat(str.length - firstDigit.length - lastDigit.length);
  let maskAddress = `${firstDigit}${mask}${lastDigit}`;
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = maskAddress;
```

```html
 <div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the substring and replace the characters you want with `*`

```js
let str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = `${str.substring(0, 6)}
${str.substring(6, str.length-6).replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,'*')}
${str.substring(str.length - 6)}`
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `String()` constructor takes only one param - the thing you want to convert to a string. You can not pass in the length like you have.

```js
let str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
let mask = new String('*').repeat(str.length - 12);

let maskAddress = str.substring(0, 6) + mask + str.substring(str.length - 6)
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = maskAddress;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a simple `for-loop` instead of using `substring` and `repeat`. Atleast the *output* will never be longer than the *input* and you will not have invalid length/count issues on smaller *input*.

```js
function mask(pinput, plength){
  let output = '';
  
  if(pinput && pinput.length){
    let length = Math.ceil(plength || (pinput.length / 4));

    for(let i=0, j=pinput.length; i<j; i++){
      output += (i >= length && i < j-length) ? '*' : pinput[i]
    }
  };
  
  return output
};

document.body.innerHTML = [
  mask('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 6),
  mask('test'),
  mask('hello there')
].join('<br/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way,

```
let n = 6, str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = str.split('').map((data, index)=>{return (index >n-1 && index<str.length-n) ? '*' : data;});
<div id="demo"></div>
```